# GetLocations fails with "Object does not exist to execute method on"

Tags: go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am having trouble with the GetLocations call. Every time I try to execute it I receive the error:

> SoftLayer_Exception: Object does not exist to execute method on.
>   (SoftLayer_Location_Group::getLocations) (HTTP 200)

This makes me think that there is something wrong with the locationService object I created but I don't understand what. Does anyone see the issue?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.New("user", "password")
    locationService := services.GetLocationGroupService(sess)
    locations, err := locationService.GetLocations()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n",err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", locations)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you got is because you need to use an identifier locationGroup ID.

Add this locationGroupId to you go code, like this example:

```
locationGroupId := 1

// Create a session
sess := session.New(username, apikey)

// Get SoftLayer_Location_Group
service := services.GetLocationGroupService(sess)

result, err := service.Id(locationGroupId).GetLocations()
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group/getLocations/

To get all locationGroupIds available you can use this go code example:

```
package main

/*
GetAllObjects

Retrieve all locationGroup objects.

Important manual pages:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group/
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Group/getAllObjects/

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
    "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // SoftLayer API username and key
    username := "set me"
    apikey   := "set me"

    // Create a session
    sess := session.New(username, apikey)

    // Get SoftLayer_Account service
    service := services.GetLocationGroupService(sess)

    result, err := service.GetAllObjects()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n Unable to retrieve all locationGroups:\n - %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    // Following helps to print the result in json format.
    jsonFormat, jsonErr := json.MarshalIndent(result,"","     ")
    if jsonErr != nil {
        fmt.Println(jsonErr)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonFormat))
}
```